# How to get c code completion in vim without clang_complete?

Tags: c, vim, ide

I need code completion in vim but since I have to use vim with +python3, clang_complete is not an option.
How can I get comfortable code completion anyway?

Since some people asked:
I need python3 support because I code python3 all the time. I know that it is possible to compile vim with both, python and python3 (that would be `+python/dyn and +python3/dyn`).
The problem with that is, that one of my addons (unfortunately I don't know which one, list of addons below) enables python3 immediately after launching vim and therefore it's not possible to use clang_complete with this setup.

addons in use:

- autoclose/
- colors-solarized/
- ctrlp/
- flake8/
- jedi-vim/
- simplyfold/
- snipmate-snippets-cuda/
- tlib_vim/
- ultisnips/
- vim-addon-mw-utils/
- vim-snippets/
- vim-surround/

Comment: What plugin are you using that requires python3?

Comment: Just so you know, Vim already comes with "code completion": `:help ins-completion` and you can build Vim with python 2 *and* 3 support.

Comment: Added some informations, @romainl I know that but I would appreciate a little bit more convenience than the built in code complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give a try to [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe). Best autocompletion plugin I've tried so far :)

It should work with Python 3.

**EDIT:**

I use it a lot for my Arduino projects and I've come up with a [`.ycm_extra_conf.py`](https://github.com/WeAreLeka/Bare-Arduino-Project/blob/master/.ycm_extra_conf.py) that works pretty well and can [auto-include](https://github.com/WeAreLeka/Bare-Arduino-Project/blob/master/.ycm_extra_conf.py#L57) the flags to the libraries you are using.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: That one looks very promising since it is under active development and has detailed documentation.

Comment: @user3648650 Yep, and the owner answers questions very quickly. I've edited my answer with a little more information that could be useful for you :)

Comment: well, it.. just does not work without `+python` (since I have only +python3): `YouCompleteMe unavailable: requires Vim compiled with Python 2.x support
`

Comment: @user3648650 why do you need Python 3?

Comment: @user3648650 Ultisnips uses Python3, so I think that's the one launching Python3. As for YCM, it does not support Python3 yet... You could try with Neovim, as uses a Python dependencies not included in the build. How did you install Python3 in the first place?